# How to consume Kafka to MySQL using Beam in Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I want to consume data from Kafka stream and write it to MySQL using Apache Beam. It's shown an error `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'apply'` on `.apply(JdbcIO.write[KV[Integer, String]]()...`

Here my full code:

```
def main(cmdlineArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create()

    val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)

    pipeline
        .apply(KafkaIO.read[Long, String]()
          .withBootstrapServers("kafka-stag.my-domain.com:31090")
          .withTopic("topic-saya")
          .withKeyDeserializer(classOf[LongDeserializer])
          .withValueDeserializer(classOf[StringDeserializer])
          .updateConsumerProperties(
            ImmutableMap.of("auto.offset.reset", "earliest".asInstanceOf[Object])
          )
          .withMaxNumRecords(5)
          .withoutMetadata()
        )
          .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()))
          .apply(JdbcIO.write[KV[Integer, String]]()
            .withDataSourceConfiguration(DataSourceConfiguration.create(
              "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
              "jdbc:mysql://localhsot:3306/mydb")
            .withUsername("root")
            .withPassword("secret"))
            .withStatement("insert into Person values(?, ?)")
            .withPreparedStatementSetter(
                (element: KV[Integer, String], query: PreparedStatement) => {
                  query.setInt(1, element.getKey())
                  query.setString(2, element.getValue())
              })
          )


    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish()
}
```

What should i do to resolve this?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you also add your imports and your dependency list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it useful to break up long chains of methods when debugging scala code.

In this case, you have three `apply(...)` chained together:

```scala
// Heads up: you'll want to specify java.lang.Long when working
// with Java code and generics... this has bitten me *many* times.

val x: PCollection[KV[java.lang.Long, String]] = pipeline
    .apply(KafkaIO.read[java.lang.Long, String]()
        .withThisAndThatConfig(...))

// Probably not what you're looking for...
// MapElements requires via() to modify the element.

val y: PCollection[String] = x
    .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()))

// Error happens below, the JdbcIO.write is expecting to be applied
// to a PCollection[KV[Integer, String]], which is not what it's getting.

val z: PDone = y
    .apply(JdbcIO.write[KV[Integer, String]]()
            .withThisAndThatConfig(...))
```

If I understand what you're looking for, you probably want to take a closer look at the middle `apply` and make sure that it's emitting the correct elements for the JdbcIO.  It's a bit of work fussing around with the two languages, but you'll probable end up with something like:

```scala
val keystoInt: SerializableFunction[KV[java.lang.Long, String], KV[Integer, String]] =
    (input: KV[java.lang.Long, String]) => KV.of(input.getKey.intValue, input.getValue)
val y: PCollection[KV[Integer, String]] = x
    .apply(MapElements
        .into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.integers, TypeDescriptors.strings))
        .via(keysToInt))
```